# Java Spigot Set the direction of the vector relative to the player's position

Tags: java, vector, bukkit, spigot

I have a problem with the correct vector alignment. I want to get a vector pointing in the same direction as the player, but with a constant Y value of 0. The point is, whatever the player's vertical and horizontal rotation, the vector's Y value was 0. The vector is always supposed to point horizontally (value 0), but keeping the direction of the player's rotation.

This picture shows the situation from the side. The red line represents an example of the player's viewing direction (up - down), and the green one the effect I want to achieve. Regardless of the direction in which the player is looking, up or down, the green line remains unchanged:

[image: Side view]

Here, in turn, I have presented this situation from the top. The red line is the player's viewing direction (left - right) and the green is the effect I want to achieve. As you can see, the player's rotation on this axis sets my vector exactly the same.

[image: View from above]

I was able to write a piece of code, but it doesn't behave correctly: the Y axis gets higher and higher as the player turns up or down. I don't know why:

```
Vector playerDirection = player.getLocation().getDirection();

Vector vector = new Vector(playerDirection.getX(), 0, playerDirection.getZ()).normalize().multiply(3);
```

How to do it correctly?

Comment: As a side note, this is one of the most well written questions I've seen under the Bukkit tag. I'm not always super active under it but I do peruse fairly often and usually the questions are borderline incoherent. For anyone else scrolling around it, this is how you should ask questions!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr:

```java
Vector vector = new Vector(-1 * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(player.getLocation().getYaw())), 0, Math.cos(Math.toRadians(player.getLocation().getYaw())));
```

---

You are missing a fundamental principal of creating a new `Vector` based on where a player is looking. I don't know the math of it very well, but I can mess around with the math of people who are better than I at Geometry.

As such, let's try to reduce the number of `Vector` variables you have defined. Taking a quick peek at the source for [`Location`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/SPIGOT/repos/bukkit/browse/src/main/java/org/bukkit/Location.java#286), we can actually create your `Vector` directly to avoid having multiple defined.

```java
public Vector getDirection() {
    Vector vector = new Vector();

    double rotX = this.getYaw();
    double rotY = this.getPitch();

    vector.setY(-Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotY)));

    double xz = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotY));

    vector.setX(-xz * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotX)));
    vector.setZ(xz * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotX)));

    return vector;
}
```

As you can see, the pitch and yaw of a player are not a 1:1 relationship. No idea why, but let's repurpose their logic.

Here's how we'll do that:

```java
public Vector getVectorForAdixe(Location playerLoc) {
    Vector vector = new Vector();
    
    double rotX = playerLoc.getYaw();
    double rotY = 0; // this is the important change from above

    // Original Code:
    // vector.setY(-Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotY)));
    // Always resolves to 0, so just do that
    vector.setY(0);

    // Original Code:
    // double xz = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotY));
    // Always resolves to 1, so just do that
    double xz = 1;

    vector.setX(-xz * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotX)));
    vector.setZ(xz * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotX)));

    return vector;
```

Nice! Now, cleaning it up a bit to remove those comments and unnecessary variables:

```java
public Vector getVectorForAdixe(Location playerLoc) {
    Vector vector = new Vector();
    
    double rotX = playerLoc.getYaw();

    vector.setY(0);

    vector.setX(-1 * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotX)));
    vector.setZ(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotX)));

    return vector;
```

Why does this math work like that? No idea! But this should almost certainly work for you. Could even inline it if you really wanted to keep it how you had it originally:

```java
Vector vector = new Vector(-1 * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(player.getLocation().getYaw())), 0, Math.cos(Math.toRadians(player.getLocation().getYaw())));
```

Closing note, if you want to be able to get the pitch/yaw FROM the vector, that code is here: https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/SPIGOT/repos/bukkit/browse/src/main/java/org/bukkit/Location.java#310